# How to rewrite url asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

using asp.net core, and I'm trying to rewrite the url from :
"product/index/region/type"
To :
"products/region-type"

region and type are words that are not fixed. Rather, they refer to the region, whatever its name, and also the type

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correct , then you should use middleware.

Try this:

```
public class UrlRewriterMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SelfRequestRouterMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if(context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("product/index/region/type")
               context.Request.Path = context.Request.Path.Value.Replace("product/index/region/type", "products/region-type");

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

and then in your startup:

```
app.UseMiddleware<UrlRewriterMiddleware>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but region and type are words that are not fixed. Rather, they refer to the region, whatever its name, and also the type.